# How to disable and enable keyboard in ubuntu?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

How to disable and enable keyboard in ubuntu?

I have a great trouble because I don't have enough space to put both `my keyboard` and `some other things` on my desk. And accidentally pressing some key may cause trouble to the system. So I am looking for one way to **lock my keyboard** temporarily. Of course I don't want to plug out the keyboard from the computer because it is so inconvenient.

How can I do with this?

xinput -list

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Optical Mouse                id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ CHICONY HP Basic USB Keyboard             id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To Disable/Enable the keyboard, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
xinput -list
```

[image]

Once you find your ID, then

```
sleep 0.1 ; xinput set-prop 9 'Device Enabled' 0 ; sleep 5 ; xinput set-prop 9 'Device Enabled' 1
```

**sleep 5** is the number of seconds (I guess) you want the keyboard to be disabled.

For more information on the xinput command see the [ManPage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xinput).

Or you can use [Lock keyboard](http://linux.softpedia.com/get/Utilities/Lock-keyboard-for-Baby-23745.shtml) utility.

Comment: How to enable keyboard again with mouse only? Is there any keyboard free solution to disable and enable keyboard back by indicator applet or just double clicking a script?

Comment: I have the same problem with @Nur

Comment: I'm testing that, will let you know shortly.

Comment: Will `xinput --enable 9` `xinput --disable 9` work the same as your command?

Comment: No.  Just try it, it doesn't do anything. :)

Comment: I know **sleep 5** means. It is one solution, but not very good as expected. I think your link for the **perl script** works, but it also locked some function of the `mouse`.

Comment: I had no issues with the mouse.  It worked fine while the keyboard was disabled.  Plus I strongly believe that nothing is a 100%.

Comment: It is true that nothing is perfect! I appreciate your help. I think I will accept the perl script.

Comment: This nice thing about the `sleep 5` here is that, if you got the id wrong and disabled your working keyboard, it'll undo itself in a few seconds. My built-in laptop keyboard keeps spamming me with 'q', which causes any open app (usually Firefox) to quit if I press the ctrl key. So with this short script, I can disable the keyboard, then hit ctrl-c (on my working wireless keyboard) to stop it being re-enabled, but if I somehow used the wireless keyboard's id, the ctrl-c won't register, so the script will continue and re-enable the keyboard.

Comment: good script here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/lk4b/

Answer (score 2):

Run `xinput -list` and find the id for `AT Translated Set 2 keyboard` as mentioned in the accepted answer. You may need to install `xinput` first.

I created the following script, and I run this via a Launcher I can click on with my mouse. Each time you click it, it toggles on or off the keyboard. Replace `13` with the ID number of your keyboard.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $(<~/.keyboard-status) == "enabled" ]]; then
    xinput --disable 13
    echo "disabled" > ~/.keyboard-status
else
    xinput --enable 13
    echo "enabled" > ~/.keyboard-status
fi
```

Comment: How would one create .keyboard_status in the first place?

Comment: Oh, I'm a moron. It's right there in the code. `echo "enabled" > ~/.keyboard-status`

Answer (score 1):

To automate both enabling and disabling Internal keyboard of laptop from cmdline, a shell script was written for my personal use at https://github.com/anitaggu/ikbdop.

A brief youtube tutorial is also available here at https://youtu.be/LvoIwqFutlg

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be easier.

Add this function at end of `.bashrc` file (or .zshrc or .profile etc.).

```
handleKeyboard() {
    if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        DEVICES_STRING=$(xinput --list | grep 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard' | tr "  " " " | tr "   " " " | tr "    " " ")
        while [[ $DEVICES_STRING = *"  "* ]]; do
            DEVICES_STRING="${DEVICES_STRING//  /}"
        done

        DEVICES_STRING=$(echo "$DEVICES_STRING" | cut -d" " -f 7)
        DEVICES_STRING="${DEVICES_STRING//id=/}"

        DEVICE_ID="$DEVICES_STRING"
    else
        DEVICE_ID=$1
    fi

    FILE_PATH=~/.keyboard-status-"$DEVICE_ID"

    FILE_STATUS=$(<"$FILE_PATH")

    if [ -z "$FILE_STATUS" ] || [ "$FILE_STATUS" = "enabled" ]; then
        xinput --disable "$DEVICE_ID"
        echo "disabled" >"$FILE_PATH"
        echo "keyboard $DEVICE_ID disabled"
    else
        xinput --enable "$DEVICE_ID"
        echo "enabled" >"$FILE_PATH"
        echo "keyboard $DEVICE_ID enabled"
    fi
}
```

And after this function you need only create an Alias like:

```
alias handle_keyboard="handleKeyboard"
```