# How to lock and unlock keyboard in Ubuntu ?

Tags: 14.04, desktop-environments

I want to lock my desktop keyboard is there any command or shortcut to do this ?

Comment: You mean so it doesn't input anything? `sudo apt-get install xtrlock` might be what you need. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=993800

Comment: yes it doest not input anything.

Comment: Did that program work?

Comment: This is stupid program, it locks my keyboard,cursor and I cant unlock those.

Comment: You just need to enter your password (type it) and it will unlock.

Comment: where I type my password ? I didn't found any password typing field when I locked keyboard.

Comment: Just type it. It's automatically listening

Comment: it works but It lock both keyboard and mouse. Is there any way to lock only keyboard not cursor so that I can scroll and click ?

Comment: I'm not sure. You can look in the config files (probably somewhere under `~/.config`).

Comment: Is it answer worthy?

Comment: @Zacharee1 If it solved the problem and you can explain how, then yes.

Comment: @Zacharee1 please type it below as an answer and I will give you a +1

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable and enable keyboard in ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/325546/how-to-disable-and-enable-keyboard-in-ubuntu) Read it if you want to disable only keyboard.

Comment: @Ron the problem with that is the keyboard is completely disabled for a certain amount of time. It's not a switch

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`xtrlock` might be what you're looking for. It disables the keyboard until you type your password. It does also disable the mouse, but you might be able to change that in the config. Install it by running `sudo apt-get install xtrlock`.

Comment: Just showing up 8 years later to say that `xtrlock` works like a charm on my Lubuntu machine. The man page does say that it is built for X11 but might not work very well on an environment that uses Wayland, so mind that.