# Custom shortcut for disabling/enabling built in laptop keyboard

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I'm currently using my laptop mainly for studying  and I sometimes need to put the paper I'm writing on , on the keyboard.

I have already found the command for disabling/enabling the mouse pad, but now I am searching for one that does the same for keyboard , or at least a guide to be able to assign a shortcut to enable/disable the keyboard. This shortcut will put it on hold as long as the specific shortcut is not pressed again after the first press that disables it.

Comment: Disabling the keyboard would prevent any key combination from re-enabling it ... otherwise it wouldn't be "disabling the keyboard". I wonder if there is a way to temporarily remap all the keys *except* for [Esc] or something like that ...

Comment: @Matigo I used to be a windows user , and i remember having an desktop app that did this , it disabled the keyboard if a shortcut is pressed , then the keyboard wont respond to any other combination besides that one shortcut , if pressed again it re enables it

Comment: I would use `Ctrl+Alt+L` to lock computer - and then you can press anything on keyboard and all programs/documents are safe. But later in need password to unlock it.

Comment: [How to disable and enable keyboard in ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/325546/how-to-disable-and-enable-keyboard-in-ubuntu)

Comment: [How to lock and unlock keyboard in Ubuntu ?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/664732/how-to-lock-and-unlock-keyboard-in-ubuntu)

Comment: @furas thank you for the links , i now have an answer , thank you so much

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable and enable keyboard in ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/325546/how-to-disable-and-enable-keyboard-in-ubuntu)

Comment: @MartinThornton Yes this link too is useful, thank you.