# How can I create an icon on the launcher to disable keyboard + rotate the screen?

Tags: scripts, keyboard, shortcut-keys, launcher, display-rotation

I have 2 in 1 pc with Ubuntu. I was wondering if there is a way to write a command which toggles an internal keyboard on and off, and rotates the screen 90 degrees left (or right), and put it on a launcher on the left. Is there any way to do that?

It would be nice, if I can just tap it to disable keyboard (+ touchpad) and rotate the screen 90 degrees, and tap one more time to go back to the right orientation with functioning keyboard (+touchpad).

Comment: Half of it (1/3) is here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/737139/how-can-i-quickly-toggle-monitor-orientation-with-a-shortcut-key/737155#737155. To get it clear: a combined action to toggle on/of internal keyboard, set the launcher on left (which is the default) and rotate screen? Then you have to mention what state should be combined with what.

Comment: @Jacob it is very close! I want to put an icon on a launcher, so that if I tap on it the screen rotates and keyboard gets disabled. Then if I tap the icon again, the screen comes back to the ordinary position and keyboard gets enabled again.

Comment: So basically I need to add disable/enable keyboard function to the python script on the link provided by Jacob.

Comment: Should be no problem. If no one does before I do, I will post today or tomorrow.

Comment: Hi Tom, posted my answer. Please mention if all is clear!

Comment: Wait, you also need to disable touchpad? Can be done, but need to know.

Comment: @Jacob I want to disable touch pad too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Script + launcher to rotate the screen *and* toggle Keyboard, in one step

The script below will both

- rotate (toggle) your screen (either left or right)
- disable (toggle) the keyboard you defined to be disabled

  [image]

  [image]

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess

# --- set the name of the screen, and the rotate direction and the id of your keyboard below
screen = "DVI-I-1"
rotate = "left"
disable = ["9", "14"]
# ---

matchline = [
    l.split() for l in subprocess.check_output(["xrandr"]).decode("utf-8").splitlines()\
    if l.startswith(screen)
    ][0]
s = matchline[
    matchline.index([s for s in matchline if s.count("+") == 2][0])+1
    ]

newset = ["normal", "1"] if s == rotate else [rotate, "0"]
subprocess.call(["xrandr", "--output", screen, "--rotate", newset[0]])
for item in disable:
    subprocess.call(["xinput", "set-prop", item, "Device Enabled", newset[1]])
```

#### How to use

1. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `rotate.py`
2. Copy the launcher below into an empty file, save it as `rotate.desktop`

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Exec=python3 /path/to/rotate.py
   Icon=preferences-desktop-keyboard
   Name=Rotate & Disable Keyboard
   Type=Application
   ```

   In the line `Exec=`, replace the `/path/to/rotate.py` by the real path to the `rotate.py` script. ***Make the `.desktop` file executable***. It will show an icon like:

   [image]
3. Now you have to find out two things:

   a. the name of your screen (the one you want to rotate): Run in a terminhal:

   ```
   xrandr
   ```

   Look for a line with "connected" in it. The first string is the screen name, looking like the example in the script. (could also be `VGA-1` or something like that)

   b. The `id` of your keyboard, the one to be disabled. Run in a terminal the command:

   ```
   xinput -list
   ```

   as described in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/325561/72216).
4. Enter the found items in the head of the script:

   ```
   # --- set the name of the screen, and the rotate direction and the id of your keyboard below
   screen = "DVI-I-1"
   rotate = "left"
   disable = ["9"]
   # ---
   ```

Now you're done, either use the `.desktop` file directly from your desktop or move it to `~/.local/share/applications` and drag it to the launcher from Dash.

If you do the latter, note that after rotating the screen, the icon will be unresponsive for appr. 7 seconds.

Have fun!

Comment: Thank you so much! It would be great if it can also disable touchpad and mouse clicks too!

Comment: Also, I think this will help loads and loads of people who uses ubuntu on their 2 in 1. If you don't mind I would like to link this to few places (perhaps a blog post or something) cheers!

Comment: I think that the `"9"` in the last line should be `keyboard`

Comment: yeah, disabling touchpad was easy. Now the problem is that keyboard gets disabled except for all the multimedia keys (brightness, airplane mode, sounds, etc... ).