# Disabling multimedia keys (brightness adjustment and airplane mode) in hp laptops

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, function-keys

I am looking for a way to disable multimedia keys (that coexist with function keys) in hp laptops using terminal commands, such that it is compatible with a script mentioned in the question

[how can i create an icon on the launcher to disable keyboard + rotate the screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/854985/how-can-i-create-an-icon-on-the-launcher-to-disable-keyboard-rotate-the-screen)

The output of `xinput -list` is

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen                          id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen Pen                      id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Wide Vision FHD Camera                 id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel Virtual Button driver               id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Wireless hotkeys                       id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

The output of `gsettings list-keys org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys` is

```
logout
screenreader
volume-mute
volume-up
window-screenshot
previous
control-center
stop
home
terminal
screenshot-clip
magnifier
help
search
custom-keybindings
magnifier-zoom-in
calculator
video-out
eject
window-screenshot-clip
area-screenshot-clip
media
www
play
email
volume-down
decrease-text-size
on-screen-keyboard
next
screenshot
increase-text-size
max-screencast-length
magnifier-zoom-out
priority
screencast
screensaver
toggle-contrast
pause
active
area-screenshot
```

**As you can see**

the list does not contain `brightness` and `airplane` mode.
Therefore disabling `id=13 AT Translated Set 2 keyboard` does not disable the brightness adjustment keys (`F2` and `F3`) and airplane mode key (`F12`).

the model that I'm using is `HP spectre x360`.

Comment: We can simply add these devices to the script in the linked question. I will do that in a few hours. It is 5 a.m here :) but where is your second keyboard?

Comment: @Jacob I don't have a second keyboard. That's the problem. Disabling id=13 will inactivate all the character keys, shift keys, return key, etc... but not multimedia keys such as brightness, sounds, airplane mode etc...

Comment: Tom, got it working perfectly! I have to run however, will add the answer later, and edit the linked script.

Comment: Hi Tom, renewed my answer. Please try and let me know the found keys.

Comment: I will remove my answer. I believe I'd need a similar laptop to find out.

Comment: @Jacob Alright. Thank you for the effort. I'm very satisfied with the fact that disabling keyboard and screen rotation can be done with a tap of a button!

Comment: I will be editing the question so that it becomes more clear.

Comment: Whatever answer might appear, I will include it in the linked script. :)